# Ruby visit web page

Tags: ruby

I need a script visiting a webpage automatically. I created this:

```
20.times do
  open(websiteURL) do |file|
    file.each{|line| puts line}
  end

  puts '--------------------'
end
```

Although it receives the actual website html code it doesn't seem to really visit the page. I tested it on a website with a working guest counter and it didn't change.

Is there an easy way to create a wabsite auto visiting script in ruby?

Bye

Comment: Could there be some kind of HTTP cache between your client script and the server?

Comment: It does a request, but does not execute the javascript. If your counter is client-side, the hit won't be counted.

Comment: There are counters which count only for different IPs (or use other similar ways) to register unique visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your best bet is to use WATIR (Web Application Testing In Ruby)

It can interact with most if not all aspects of a web page and will actually drive a browser (IE, Firefox using firewatir, or chrome using watir-webdriver I think)

Head here to http://watir.com/ and give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

[Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) could help you interacting with a website in an elegant way.

Comment: Will this execute JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

if the counter is implemented in javascript it may not be triggered by your script

Answer (score 1):

There's not just "visit page" behavior, unless you can use full-blown web browser which behaves like real web browser like creators of your page expect to count.

What could count is downloading some image (maybe hidden), starting AJAX call to server by code from javascript file loaded on page, or just fetching html file (which in your case didn't worked). If you want to build full browser-like script, then you need to fetch all images and other files included in html (and probably parse html first), and execute somehow javascripts if it's necessary. But I would spend some time trying to find what really is counted and keep things simple.